# Please support language highlighting with ada tag

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting for the Ada programming language currently works with `lang-ada` (see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19531150/347964)). The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/237607) does not mention the language code (and it requires this question for adding the language to the list). Also, it would be great if syntax highlighting would be supported by the `ada` tag.

Comment: `lang-ada` does not exist. It's using some random language via auto-detection.

Comment: Hmm. Then why does it do that only when the post specifies `<!-- language: lang-ada -->`?

Comment: Because all of the tags on that question are set to `<none>`, so if nothing is set manually, no syntax highlighting is used.

Comment: Interesting. You should post that as answer.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is clearly being used, and appears reasonable, only when `<!-- language: lang-ada -->` is present

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Highlight.js: For Real, Please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278141/highlight-js-for-real-please)